# How to set tier pricing per category rather than setting for individual product

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

It's very time consuming to add tier pricing for each product, is there any way to do this for all the products in a particular category?
or is there any plugin already available that will do this job?

thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a solution myself. a plugin was there actually that does this.
with that plugin we can set tier pricing for multiple products across categories
here is the link : http://wiki.bluejalappeno.com/home/tiered-pricing-across-multiple-products/configuration-of-tiered-pricing-across-multiple-products

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can not do it. What You can do a bulk update on products. Or even, which I think is not what you are looking for, in a category go to Promotions > Catalogue Price Rule and you can set up discounts to products in particular categories.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. anyways i found out a plugin that will do this for multiple products across categories.